# Issue Installing Packages

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I am trying to install the `spomet` and `accounts-entry` packages with meteorite and I'm receiving this:

```
smart.json changed.. installing from smart.json
smart.json changed.. installing from smart.json
✓ iron-router
    tag: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router.git#v0.6.1

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/sources/git.js:151
hrow "There was a problem checking out " + self.checkoutType + ": " + (self.co
                                                                ^
There was a problem checking out tag: v0.6.1
```

What does this mean? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I periodically get this error with a variety of meteorite packages.

The fix that usually works for me is to kill the ~/.meteorite directory by running...

```
mrt uninstall --system
```

...then trying again.

Answer (score 2):

The problem's with iron-router.

It depends on the npm module connect. The npmjs repository is having a bit of trouble at the moment try in a few hours perhaps.

You could try forcing an install:

In your project:

```
cd packages
git clone https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router.git
```

This should forcibly install iron-router in. And if not give more details as an error.

Comment: this problem still persist. Is there something else it could be?

Comment: Mine's working now. Has yours worked before yesterday? It could be a firewall issue too.
Try this (updated my answer)

Comment: I've removed iron-router, manually, and forcefully reinstalled it. I've noticed that every time i've installed iron-router previously, it was installing 0.5.4, even though it should have been 0.6+. I've now just installed all the packages I wanted forcefully.